# How to get random array key having value in bounds

Tags: php, arrays, random, range, filtering

I've got this array:

```
$tz = array(
    'Usa' => '-7',
    'Ecuador' => '-5',
    'Bolivia' => '-4',
    'Uruguay' => '-3',
    'London' => '0',
    'France' => '2',
    'Spain' => '2',
    'Germany' => '2',
    'Greece' => '3',
    'Rusia' => '3',
    'Romania' => '3',
    'Pakistan' => '5',
    'China' => '8' 
);
```

My goal is to get a random country from those having offset >= 0 and <= '3'.

I tried:

```
$country = array_rand($tz);
echo 'Key: "'.$country.'" offset: "'.$tz[$country].'"<br>';
```

that returns
Key: "Romania" offset: "+3:00", but i know.. is not the right way.

How to do this? Any help?

**As MrRP said problem solved with this**

```
$filtered = array_filter($tz, function($v) { return $v >= 0 && $v <=3; });
$country = array_rand($filtered);
echo 'Key: "'.$country.'" offset: "'.$filtered[$country].'"<br>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$filtered = array_filter($tz, function($v) { return $v >= 0 && $v <=3; });
```

Then you can use the `array_rand` on the filtered array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code....

```
$tz = array(
   'Usa' => '-7',
   'Ecuador' => '-5',
   'Bolivia' => '-4',
   'Uruguay' => '-3',
   'London' => '0',
   'France' => '2',
   'Spain' => '2',
   'Germany' => '2',
   'Greece' => '3',
   'Rusia' => '3',
   'Romania' => '3',
   'Pakistan' => '5',
   'China' => '8'
```

);

do{

```
   $t = array_rand($tz);
```

}

while(!($tz[$t]>=0)&&($tz[$t]<=3));

echo '';print_r($t);die;

Answer (score 1):

Too easy as a one-liner:

> ```
> $country=array_rand(array_intersect($tz,range(0,3)));
> ```

Your echo line:

```
echo 'Key: "',$country,'" offset: "',$tz[$country],'"<br>';
```

Explanation:

create your desired range of wanted values: `range(0,3); // creates [0,1,2,3]`

create array of qualifying countries: `array_intersect($tz,range(0,3));`

```
array('London'=>'0',
      'France'=>'2',
      'Spain'=>'2',
      'Germany'=>'2',
      'Greece'=>'3',
      'Rusia'=>'3',
      'Romania'=>'3'
)
```

Then just pluck a random key from the list, done!

This method is efficient and generates no unnecessary global variables.

`array_intersect()` generates the same filtered array as `array_filter()` in MrRP's answer.  The difference is that my method will only be doing one conditional operation on each iteration (like in_array()) instead of two separate conditions on each iteration: greater-than-or-equal-to & less-than-or-equal-to.

Comment: You guys are awesome!!
Thanks a lot all of you..!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this. Couldn't able to understand your query exactly but I think this is what you want maybe.

```
$tz = array(
    'Usa' => '-7',
    'Ecuador' => '-5',
    'Bolivia' => '-4',
    'Uruguay' => '-3',
    'London' => '0',
    'France' => '2',
    'Spain' => '2',
    'Germany' => '2',
    'Greece' => '3',
    'Rusia' => '3',
    'Romania' => '3',
    'Pakistan' => '5',
    'China' => '8'
);

$lowerBound = 0;
$upperBound = 3;

$newDataSet = array();
foreach ($tz as $key => $value) {
    if($value<=$upperBound && $value>=$lowerBound) {
        $newDataSet[] = $key;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newDataSet);
echo '</pre>';

// Fetch random Country from the new list
$rand_keys = array_rand($newDataSet, 1);

echo '<br>Here is a random country : '.$newDataSet[$rand_keys] . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your try mi6crazyheart... MrRP has a better way to solve this..